# Default Bootstrap-table size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I have a bootstrap-table that has multiple headers and an `addAction()` function that `push()` the information from my API in the table. Everything works fine except if I have no information to push, my table is very small and isn't really aesthetically pleasing to look at.

By default, Bootstrap-table sets the table size very small and writes *There is no data to display* in the table. I would like to replace this by a default table size value that is just empty inside.

Where I make the headers and call `addAction()`

```
return (
  <div onLoad={addAction(pageSize, this.props.data.viewer)}>
      <BootstrapTable hover data={action} headerStyle={{ background: '#DEDEDE' }}>
        <TableHeaderColumn dataField='process' width='200px'>
          <p>
            Process
          </p>
        </TableHeaderColumn>
      </BootstrapTable>
    </div>
);
```

addAction()

```
function addAction (quantity, props) {
  action = [];
   for (let i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
    if (props.actions.items[i] != null) {
      action.push({
       process: props.actions.items[i].request.process.description,
      });
    }
   }
}
```

To summarize, if props.actions has no items, I want to show an empty grid with a fixed size.

Is it possible and if so, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few properties of [react-bootstrap-table](http://allenfang.github.io/react-bootstrap-table/docs.html), that you can use to set the height of the table:

**1.** Setting the height of the table: [reference](http://allenfang.github.io/react-bootstrap-table/docs.html#height)

```
<BootstrapTable data={ data } height='120px'>
```

**2.** Setting the height of headers: [reference](http://allenfang.github.io/react-bootstrap-table/docs.html#headerStyle)

```
<BootstrapTable
  headerStyle={{ height: 200px }}>
    //...
</BootstrapTable>
```

**3.** Setting the height of the body of the table: [reference](http://allenfang.github.io/react-bootstrap-table/docs.html#bodyStyle)

```
<BootstrapTable
  bodyStyle={{ height: '200px' }}>
    //...
</BootstrapTable>
```

Comment: I like your answer#1 but how would I implement it using an `if` in the `<...>`?

Comment: I would like the height to be 120px only if `actions` has no `items`

Comment: like this you can use condition:`<BootstrapTable data={ data } height={condition ? '120px' : '200px'}>`

Comment: And if I don't want a fixed size if the condition isn't met?

Comment: set as `""` it will get ignored, like this: `height={condition ? '120px' : ''}`

Comment: Excellent! Worked perfectly in my situation. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**put your logic in else section . when prop.actions.item is not null then if section will run. but when it null then else section will be running . there you can put your logic for giving message or putting empty td with colspan.**

```
 if (props.actions.items[i] != null) {
          action.push({
           process: props.actions.items[i].request.process.description,
          });
    else
    {
    do some thing here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

bootstrap table can take whole area of parent element.

when data is not coming then make a single td in a table and use colspan . after that put and empty string to that. then size will be ok.
 &nbsp

Comment: Where exactly would I use colspan?